# SQL server insert data from table into an XML variable

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqlxml

How can I insert a whole bunch of rows into an XML variable without using a cursor?
I know I can do

```
SET @errors.modify('insert <error>{ sql:variable("@text") }</error> as last into /errors[1]')
```

to insert the value of a variable, but I want to basically do

```
SET @errors.modify(SELECT 'insert <error>{ sql:column("text") }</error>' FROM table)
```

which, of course, isn't legal syntax.

Edit: Obviously my question wasn't clear. What I want is to be able to do like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(text nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('Message 2')
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('Message 3')

DECLARE @errors xml
SET @errors = '<errors><error>Message 1</error></errors>'

SET @errors.modify('INSERT EVERYTHING FROM my_table MAGIC STATEMENT')
```

And after running this code, @errors should contain

```
<errors>
  <error>Message 1</error>
  <error>Message 2</error>
  <error>Message 3</error>
</errors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on marc's answer, here is a solution that works for SQL Server 2005:

```
CREATE TABLE #my_table(text nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES('Message 2')
INSERT INTO #my_table VALUES('Message 3')

DECLARE @errors xml
SET @errors = '<errors><error>Message 1</error></errors>'

SELECT @errors = CAST(@errors AS nvarchar(max)) + '<new>' + (SELECT text AS 'error' FROM #my_table FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS) + '</new>'

SET @errors = CAST(@errors AS nvarchar(max)) + '<new>' + @newErrors + '</new>'
SET @errors.modify('insert (/new/*) as last into (/errors)[1]')
SET @errors.modify('delete (/new)')

SELECT @errors

DROP TABLE #my_table
```

Will return

```
<errors>
  <error>Message 1</error>
  <error>Message 2</error>
  <error>Message 3</error>
</errors>
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't this simpler?

```
set ErrorXML=(SELECT * from #MyTable FOR XML AUTO)
```

Comment: It's simpler, but it will replace the content of the variable rather than append to it.

Answer (score 1):

LAST UPDATE:

OK, now that the question is much clearer, he's the solution - hopefully!!

```
DECLARE @errors xml
SET @errors = '<errors><error>Message 1</error></errors>'

DECLARE @newErrors XML 

SELECT @newErrors = (SELECT text AS 'error'
FROM dbo.my_table 
FOR XML PATH(''), ELEMENTS)

SELECT @errors, @newErrors

SET @errors.modify('insert sql:variable("@newErrors") as last into (/errors)[1]')

SELECT @errors
```

This gives me

@errors at the beginning

```
<errors><error>Message 1</error></errors>
```

@newError after the "magic" SELECT:

```
<error>Message 2</error><error>Message 3</error>
```

@errors after the UPDATE:

```
<errors>
    <error>Message 1</error>
    <error>Message 2</error>
    <error>Message 3</error>
</errors>
```

Is **THAT** what you're looking for?? :-)

---

(old answers - not what the OP was looking for.....)

You need to look at the `.nodes()` function in SQL XQuery - this will break up an XML 
variable into a list of XML nodes, based on an XPath expression (that references some point in your XML where you are likely to have an enumeration of nodes of the same structure), and it gives them a "virtual" table and column name.

Based on that "Table.Column" element, you can select single values from that XML node - either attributes or sub-elements - and you get these back as "atomic" values, e.g. as INT, VARCHAR(x), whatever you need. These values can be inserted into the table:

```
INSERT dbo.YourTable(col1, col2, col3, ..., colN)
  SELECT
     Error.Column.value('@attr1[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
     Error.Column.value('subitem[1]', 'int'),
     .....
     Error.Column.value('subitemN[1]', 'DateTime')
  FROM
     @xmldata.nodes('/error') AS Error(Column)
```

**UPDATE:** ok, so you want to do the opposite - turn relational data into XML - that's even easier :-)

```
DECLARE @NewXmlContent XML

SELECT @NewXmlContent = 
       (SELECT
          col1 as '@ID',
          col2 as 'SomeElement',
          .....
          colN as 'LastElement'
       FROM 
          dbo.YourTable
       WHERE
           ....
       FOR XML PATH('element'), ROOT('root')
       )

UPDATE YourOtherTable
SET XmlField.modify('insert sql:variable("@NewXmlContent") 
                     as last into (/XPath)[1]')
WHERE (some condition)
```

This will give you something like this in @NewXmlContent:

```
<root>
   <element ID="(value of col1)">
      <SomeElement>(value of col2)</SomeElement>
      .....
      <LastElement>(value of colN)</LastElement>
   </element>
</root>
```

and the UPDATE statement with the `.modify()` call will actually insert that content into an existing XML field in your database. This is the only way to get XML contents into an existing XML column - there's no way of directly referencing another XML column inside a XML fragment being inserted....

The new "FOR XML PATH" syntax is very powerful and flexible and allows you to do just about anything.

And of course, you can easily store that into a XML variable.

Marc

Comment: Yes, but I want to do the opposite: Populate the xml variable with data from a table.

Comment: I am aware of the FOR XML syntax, but can you tell me how to use it to append to an existing variable, rather than to replace the value entirely.

Comment: Ah ok - that wasn't clear from your original question - answer updated again

Comment: That technique should also work for updating an existing SQL variable of type XML with new contents, btw.

Comment: Your latest solution looks promising, but unfortunately it fails with the error message "XQuery: SQL type 'xml' is not supported in XQuery". If changing the type of @newErrors to nvarchar(max), it fails with the error 'XQuery [modify()]: Only non-document nodes can be inserted. Found "xs:string ?"'.

Comment: Btw, I'm using SQL Server 2k5.

Comment: Ah, that's the problem, I guess - I'm on SQL Server 2008, and the ability to use "sql:variable" in INSERT statements is one of the few new xml-related features of SQL Server 2008. I don't think you'll be able to do this in SQL Server 2005, unfortunatly :-(

Comment: Doesn't this suggest that `sql:variable` is valid for sql2k5? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: @Tr1stan: yes, **for `.query()` calls**. But only for those. Check out the [What's new in SQL Server 2008 XML (DOC file)](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/c/d/acd8e043-d69b-4f09-bc9e-4168b65aaa71/WhatsNewSQL2008XML.doc) and read: *SQL Server 2008 adds support for using an **xml variable in an insert expression** to insert XML data into an existing XML structure.*

Comment: @marc_s bugger, that's just put a stopper on the query I've written with .modify if it won't work with 2k5 - thanks for the clarification.